# need to do a subquery in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to write the Linq version of the SQL script below. But, I couldnt do it. I couldnt do the `SUBQUERY` part. `T_PROJECT` and `T_SERVICE_TRANSACTION`  tables are linked with each other by `PROJECT_ID` and `P.ID`, it is a foreign key. How can I write the Linq version of it?

```
SELECT P.PROJECT_NAME, P.TOTAL_TIME, 
   (
        P.TOTAL_TIME - ( SELECT SUM(GIVEN_SERVICE_TIME)  
                         FROM T_SERVICE_TRANSACTION 
                         WHERE PROJECT_ID=P.ID )
   ) 
FROM T_PROJECT P
```

Comment: Do you your entity classes look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something along these lines..

```
var result = Project.Select(p => new {
    ProjectName = p.ProjectName, 
    TotalTime = p.TotalTime, 
    CustomColumn = p.TotalTime - p.T_Service_Transactions
       .Sum( t=> t.GivenServiceTime)
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I think it will work but I am getting error ..... System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`10[System.String,System.Nullabl......

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ No Problem! I'm not entirely sure on the error without seeing the rest of your code but you may need to project the results into your own type if you are consuming the results elsewhere. It sounds like you have a typed dictionary which isn't going to accept the list, or the anonymous type inside the list.  You can use the .ToDictionary method - first argument produces the key(probably p => p.ProjectName), The second produces the value which would need to match the type expected by your dictionary.